# References for gradient systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, gradient-flows

I am interested in the gradient system

$$\dot{x}(t)=-\nabla f(x(t))$$

where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{1,1}$ function (that is, a differentiable function whose gradient is Lipschitz continuous). I would be grateful if someone could propose some reference books related to this system.

Comment: [Steepest descent/gradient descent as dynamical system](http://mathoverflow.net/q/252963/91764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is convex, then the gradient flow $\dot{x} = - \nabla f (x)$ is doing continuous-time gradient descent. A book on gradient flows is the following one:

- Uwe Helmke, John B. Moore, [Optimization and Dynamical Systems](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B04.PDF), 2nd edition, March 1996.

Comment: @Blind Page 20 of the book (page 31 of the PDF file).

Comment: Do you reccomend more references. I am grateful to you if you could give your comments on the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802541/elementary-properties-of-gradient-systems