# Examples of a gradient flow

Tags: optimization, reference-request, applications, gradient-descent, gradient-flows

Suppose we have a gradient flow in $\mathbb{R}^n$ :

$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=-\nabla F(x(t)), \qquad x(0)=x_0.$$

where $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}^n$. What are some classical examples (or toy models) from physics, chemistry or biology for the above Euclidean gradient flow? References are also welcome!

Comment: Take a look at [this book](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1802503/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks :-), do you know of an example which isnt related to neural nets / machine learning etc?